# Concept of creating Array of structures in C with three properties

Tags: c, arrays, struct

Hi all what I wish to create is some code in C that will allow me to store R,G,B values separately (this will be from an image), I have done some research and assume that using Array of structures to be the best way but still unsure. I then wish to access values from these structures to carry out some simple calculations. The problem I am having is getting my head around accessing the structure/arrays. I'm finding the conceptual part quite difficult if anyone can use a simple example it doesn't have to be relevant to my task but some sample code 3 properties to one structure would be helpful showing how the values can be accessed. I am also looking to understand how I load the structure with values. Any tips or help would be appreciated.

Comment: I can also come around and put the bins  out - then do the washing up followed by cleaning the windows.

Comment: These are very basic fundamentals of C. Arrays are one of the first things one learns. I would suggest learning the fundamentals first before asking questions about specific applications.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Hi You can Implement a three dimensional array to store the RGB values and then do the operation you want.
The dummy code looks some thing like this:

```
    #define TOTAL_NO_OF_PIXEL 1080  //For example total 1080 no of pixels are there
    int RGBcolor[3][TOTAL_NO_OF_PIXEL];
    int main()
    {
        for(int cnt=0;cnt<TOTAL_NO_OF_PIXEL;cnt++)
        {
            RGBcolor[0][cnt] = RED;
            RGBcolor[1][cnt] = GREEN;
            RGBcolor[2][cnt] = BLUE;
        }    
        return 0;
    }
```

Hope this Helps.

Comment: There is no 3D array.

Comment: @Sudipta Hi just to check does the for loop setup the colours to be able to take 1080 values and thank you for this response, if I wish to add values into the arrays what should I do, also to access these values from the array what should I do thanks again

Comment: @artmaster547 you can take integer variables for reading the RED, GREEN and BLUE Values from each pixel and then you access each pixel to get the those then you can store them in the array. Once the you have stored all the values in the array you can access the array as per your requirement. Here I am taking 1080 as total no of pixels in the image. For example if you have an image having resolution of 60x40 you will have total 2400 no of pixels.

Answer (score -1):

The definition of the structure could be:

```
  struct{
  unsigned char r,g,b ;
  /* unsigned char holds values 0…255 for 24 bit color */
  }rgb;
```

To declare variables:

```
struct rgb cyan;
```

To assign values:

```
cyan.r=0;
cyan.g=255;
cyan.b=255;
```

To print:

```
printf("%03d",(cyan.r),… and so on…
```

1) you may want to use pointers instead.

2) using **typedef** makes the syntax more compact.